# spring, how to read in all properties for my bean

Tags: spring

I need to get a Properties object into my spring bean so I can iterate over all the properties.  I have the following in my spring test file so test properties override production properties like 10.x.x.x to 0.0.0.0 as a bind address

```
<context:property-placeholder location="esb-project-config.properties, test-esb-project-config.properties"/>
```

How to get the properties file injected that represents the properties of the final resulting set of those two files?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a properties bean and refer to it by id:

```
<bean id="composedProperties"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="locations">
    <list>
      <value>esb-project-config.properties</value>
      <value>test-esb-project-config.properties</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Properties from files listed later in the list take precedence over listed earlier.

Comment: wouldn't that break all the beans that use the {@Value} to read in the properties then?  I am bootstrapping JSR 330 into our stuff so we can start using javax.inject.Inject instead of {@AutoWire} and don't want to break existing functionality.

Comment: This is just a definition of merged `Properties` object you can iterate upon. To use it in `@Value` etc. add `<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="composedProperties">`

Answer (score 0):

I may be late but It can help others.There is another solution you can try using "*".

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:*.properties"/>
```

Here It will load all files which has **"properties"** extension.